# Which .Net-compatible architectures are not little-endian?

Tags: .net

The [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kftcaf9.aspx) class has a field [IsLittleEndian](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) which, according to the documentation:

> Indicates the byte order ("endianness") in which data is stored in this computer architecture.

I notice in Reflector that the field is hard-coded to true in the static constructor of BitConverter.

So my question is, do I need to take account of IsLittleEndian when using the BitConverter - in other words, are there any .Net implementations running on big-endian platforms? And if not, what was the purpose of the field in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLI standard does not proscribe any particular Endianness, so if you want your program to be portable, you should *not* depend on a particular byte order... unless of course in scenarios where a particular byte ordering is required, such as with some data exchange protocols (thanks to user The Moof for pointing this out).

> **From the CLI Annotated Standard** (p.161) — Partition I, section 12.6.3: "Byte Ordering":
>
> *For data types larger than 1 byte, the byte ordering is dependent on the target CPU. Code that depends on byte ordering may not run on all platforms. [...]*

I suspect that you saw a hard-coded value for `IsLittleEndian` in Reflector because when you downloaded/installed the .NET Framework on your machine, that particular installation package was targeted at a particular platform (e.g. Intel x86, which is Little Endian).

I could thus imagine that there are other installation packages of the .NET framework that have `IsLittleEndian` hard-wired to return a different value, depending on the platform that particular installation targets.

Comment: IP packets are extremely byte-order dependent, so you need to keep that in mind when talking about portability.  It's rare to have a project come through that needs low-level network programming, but they're out there.

Answer (score 4):

SOME of the systems that the [.NET Micro Framework](https://web.archive.org/web/20101223163114/http://www.microsoft.com:80/netmf/hardware/default.mspx) runs on are (or can be...) big-endian. [Version 4.1 introduced support for big-endian architectures](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312032734/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netmfteam/archive/2010/07/19/netmf-versions-4-1-released-to-web.aspx).

You'd probably know if you were running on the micro framework, however...

Answer (score 4):

The .Net Micro Framework 4.1 supports big-endian - [Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netmfteam/archive/2010/07/19/netmf-versions-4-1-released-to-web.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by ".Net implementations". I'm not aware of Microsoft .NET Framework version for big-endian platform (but see other answers). But if you mean CLI/CLR implementation, then both [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) and [DotGNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/pnet.html) have versions for big-endian machines. Mono runs at least on Solaris 10 on Sparc and on Mac OS X on PowerPC. DotGNU has much wider list of available platforms.

Answer (score 1):

If you're MSIL you don't get that guarantee.

Even if it's true for all current architectures, you have no guarantee I don't port .NET to Alpha or PDP11 tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

The XBox360 is BigEndian. Robert Unoki from Microsoft has a good [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robunoki/archive/2006/04/05/568737.aspx) about the importance of checking the IsLittleEndian flag - and the bugs that occurred in porting the CLR to XBox360 when the Microsoft developers failed to do so.