# Mono Endianness

Tags: c#, .net, mono, endianness

with .NET things are fairly simple - it is all (including ARM ASFAIK) running little endian .

The question that I have is: what is happing on Mono and (potentially) big endian systems? Do the bits reverse (when compared to x86) in Int32 / Int64 structure or does the framework force little endian rule-set?

Thanks

Comment: I would guess it will be defined by the CLR spec

Comment: It can't hide endianness, far too expensive.  See BitConverter.IsLittleEndian.

Answer (score 13):

Your assertion that all MS .NET are little endian is not correct. It depends on the architecture that you are running on - the CLR spec says so:

> **From the CLI Annotated Standard** (p.161) — Partition I, section 12.6.3: "Byte Ordering":
>
> *For data types larger than 1 byte, the byte ordering is dependent on the target CPU. Code that depends on byte ordering may not run on all platforms. [...]*

(taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685624/which-net-compatible-architectures-are-not-little-endian/3685816#3685816) SO answer)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003380/net-reversing-byte-order) answer for more information on the internals of `BitConverter` and how it handles endianness.

Comment: This brings in an interesting question: "..dependent on the target CPU..." so what happens with mono running on Little Endian windows running on top of Big Endian ARM CPU? [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/04c92ef9-e38e-415f-8958-ec9f7c196fd3) MSFT Support forum

Comment: Isn't that the CLI spec rather than the CLR spec? (The part you've quoted says CLI.) All this demonstrates is that the CLI spec accommodates the possibility of a big-endian implementation. This would not contradict the proposition that all flavours of the CLR (i.e., Microsoft's implementation) are little-endian. And as far as I know, they all are. Are you aware of any supported Microsoft .NET implementation that's big-endian? (I think Rotor, aka SSCLI supported it, but that's not the CLR.)

Answer (score 4):

A list of behavioral changes I can think of at the moment (unchecked and incomplete):

- [IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/653kcke1.aspx) and [IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1886wea.aspx)
- Nearly everything in [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx)
- [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx) and [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) (**EDIT**: From documentation: "BinaryReader reads this data type in little-endian format.")
- [Binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx)
- Everything that reads and writes Unicode in default encoding from/to streams ([UnicodeEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) (**EDIT**: Default is defined as little endian)

and of course every (runtime library) function using these.

Usually Microsoft doesn't mention endianness in their docs - with some strange exceptions. For instance, [BinaryReader.ReadUInt16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.binaryreader.readuint16.aspx) is defined to read little endian. Nothing mentioned for the other methods. One may assume that binary serialization is always little-endian, even on big-endian machines.

Note that XNA on XBox360 is [big-endian](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robunoki/archive/2006/04/05/568737.aspx), so this not just a theoretical problem with Mono.

Comment: Sounds like I need to do some testing ... anyone has a good working QEMU image for ARM cpu with linux / mono installed on it?

Answer (score 3):

c#/.Net does not make any claims on endian.  int32/64 are atomic not structures.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know such conversion would happen outside the scope of your code and hidden to you. It's called "managed code" for some reasons, including such potential issues.

Comment: There are a number of places where endianness affects the code. `BitConverter`, `Buffer.BlockCopy`, unsafe code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To know if bytes are "reversed", just check `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    // reverse bytes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering how similar .Net and Mono are by design, I'd say they *probably* handle endianness the same.

You can always test it by creating a managed int with a known value, then using reflection or marshalling to access the memory and take a look.

Comment: The only problem that I have is access to a big endian system with framework on it:) What I'm specifically looking to do is to convert an integer to a byte array -- the array needs to be in a big endian order for things to work; Since the code might end up on a big endian system at some point, I'm trying to make sure I don't end up reversing the bytes when it is not needed.